# $\xi$ be a primitive cube root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone tell me first of all the below problem is wrong or okay?I am not able to figure out how to solve

$\xi$ be a primitive cube root of unity define $A=\begin{pmatrix}\xi^{-1}&0\\0&\xi\end{pmatrix}$, for a vector $v=(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ define $$|v|_A=\sqrt{|vAv^T|}$$ if $w=(1,1)$ what is the value of $|w|_A$?

Comment: You have an extra coordinate on your vectors.

Comment: Or a missing row and column on $A$.

Comment: And the notational difference $|v|_A$ vs. $|w_A|$ is probably a typo.

Comment: I have edited...

Comment: @MJD The glass was half full, not half empty, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem involves plugging numbers into an expression. Where are you having issues?

Did you get as far as to write it down? That is,

$$wAw^T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\xi^{-1}&0\\0&\xi\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}~?$$

If so, did you evaluate it by using matrix multiplication? Do you know how to simplify the resulting expression into a real number? After that, you just take absolute value and square root.

To simplify the resulting complex number expression into the real number it denotes, consider either de Moivre's formula for complex exponentials (and how to write roots of unity as complex exponentials), or much more simply, use the relation $\xi^2+\xi+1=0$ (this follows from rewriting the expression $\xi^3=1$ as $(\xi-1)(\xi^2+\xi+1)=0$ and then dividing by $\xi-1$).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\xi^{-1}+\xi=\frac{1+\xi^2}{\xi}
$$

Since $\xi$ is a primitive cubic root of $1$, $\xi^2+\xi+1=0$, so $1+\xi^2=-\xi$;
hence
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\xi^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \xi\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
=\xi^{-1}+\xi
=\frac{1+\xi^2}{\xi}
=\frac{-\xi}{\xi}=-1.
$$
Thus
$$
|v|_A=\sqrt{\lvert-1\rvert}=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

An idea with a probably different, simpler approach:

First, pay attention to the fact that $\,|\xi|=1\iff \xi^{-1}=\bar\xi\;$ , so

$$(1\;1)\begin{pmatrix}\bar\xi&0\\0&\xi\end{pmatrix}\binom11=\bar\xi+\xi=2\,\text{Re}(\xi)=2\cos\frac{2\pi}3=-1\implies|w|_A=1$$